# Validar coma al separar miles con expresión regular

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular, ¿Que debo agregar para que sea aceptada la coma al separar cifras en miles? por ejemplo 111,111.00, considerando que valido que sean hasta 10 enteros un punto y hasta 10 decimales.

> ^(\d{1,10})(.\d{1,10})?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente: `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$`

```
^                   # Inicio de línea
    \d{1,3}         # Un número de 1 a 3 veces
    (?:,\d{3})*     # Un conjunto de (coma + 3 números) repetidos 0 o más veces
    (?:\.\d+)?      # Opcionalmente un punto y números
$                   # Fin de línea
```

**[Demo en regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4UCuyb/1/)**

**Demo con Javascript:**

```js
let numero = '111,111.111';
var patron = new RegExp(/\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/);
console.log(patron.test(numero));
```

Answer (score 1):

te propongo una solución sin expresiones regulares, con el uso de `toLocaleString`

```js
let num = 111111.111;
console.log(num.toLocaleString('en-US'));
```

además tiene una serie de opciones que te pueden ser de utilidad, te dejo un vínculo

[ToLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: es que si necesitaba la expresion regular ya que valido que sean hasta 10 enteros un punto y hasta 10 decimales :(

Comment: te aconsejo agregar eso a la pregunta que formulaste